# how to change 303 redirect to a 301 Redirect in PHP

Tags: php

Im using this Joomla 1.5 plugin to do redirects. Works great but it returns a "303 see other" redirect status instead of the SEO friendly 301

Is there anything that can be done to the below code for the plugin to make it a 301 redirects?

```
<?php
/**
 * JRedirect plugin
 * 
 * @author Ross Farinella
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @license GPL
*/

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

global $mainframe;
$mainframe->registerEvent('onAfterRoute', 'plgSystemCheckJRedirect');

/**
 * Checks to see if the current URL being requested is one of the "special" URLs 
 *  and redirects the application as necessary
 */
function plgSystemCheckJRedirect() 
{
global $mainframe;

// get the plugin parameters
$tmp = JPluginHelper::getPlugin("system","jredirect");
$params = new JParameter($tmp->params);

// get the current URI
$current = JRequest::getURI(); // "/something.html"

$urls = $params->get('urls');
$urls = explode("\n",$urls);
foreach($urls as $url) 
{
    // get the user-entered urls
    list($toCheck,$toRedirect) = explode("|",$url);

    // check if we're at this url
    if($current == "/".$toCheck) {
        // do the redirect
        $mainframe->redirect($toRedirect);
    }
}
}


?>
```

Comment: We need to se the insides of the function `$mainframe->redirect()`, but it should be as simple as adding a `header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");` call before the `header("Location:")`.

Comment: Many other examples in the "Related" questions over to the right of here have examples on how it is done, when you find the right place to place it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Im just trying to find where to add that, Im using a third party plugin so Im going to assume I can't put that piece of code in the above file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JApplication%3a%3aredirect/1.5) (or rather, [the source](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/development/tags/1.5.x/1.5.23/libraries/joomla/application/application.php&view=markup)), you should be able to do so by changing

```
$mainframe->redirect($toRedirect);
```

to

```
$mainframe->redirect($toRedirect,'','message',true);
```

So:

```
<?php
/**
 * JRedirect plugin
 * 
 * @author Ross Farinella
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @license GPL
*/

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

global $mainframe;
$mainframe->registerEvent('onAfterRoute', 'plgSystemCheckJRedirect');

/**
 * Checks to see if the current URL being requested is one of the "special" URLs 
 *  and redirects the application as necessary
 */
function plgSystemCheckJRedirect() 
{
global $mainframe;

// get the plugin parameters
$tmp = JPluginHelper::getPlugin("system","jredirect");
$params = new JParameter($tmp->params);

// get the current URI
$current = JRequest::getURI(); // "/something.html"

$urls = $params->get('urls');
$urls = explode("\n",$urls);
foreach($urls as $url) 
{
    // get the user-entered urls
    list($toCheck,$toRedirect) = explode("|",$url);

    // check if we're at this url
    if($current == "/".$toCheck) {
        // do the redirect
        $mainframe->redirect($toRedirect,'','message',true);
    }
}
}


?>
```